# Remove all tags from the text while typing with Tinymce editor plugin, wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce-4

when i write a text using TinyMCE editor, white spaces are replaced by p tags and new lines are replaced by "rn", i want to remove all this formating, just want to keep a simple text that i have entered.

here is the example text out put:
"<p style="margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;">Cras lacinia, magna vel finibus mattis, neque nisl gravida nulla, vel posuere dui nisi vel arcu. Integer tristique dignissim dolor, vel tristique orci. Ut auctor ultrices ullamcorper. Suspendisse in eros nisi. Nulla sodales vel nulla quis sollicitudin. Sed suscipit nulla id maximus eleifend. Phasellus sed enim vel dui interdum cursus. Morbi ipsum nibh, iaculis nec iaculis vitae, malesuada at libero. Nunc convallis iaculis ex, vel gravida odio sollicitudin nec. Fusce volutpat mi augue, ut efficitur mi aliquet sit amet. In luctus viverra metus, posuere suscipit nulla molestie sed. Etiam sem nunc, ultricies eget quam non, elementum commodo nibh. Nullam lorem diam, tempor id vehicula eu, dignissim quis arcu. Sed accumsan suscipit lacus in pretium. Donec venenatis turpis ac commodo suscipit.

rn<p style="margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;">Pellentesque enim lacus, volutpat ut rutrum vel, venenatis vel velit. Aliquam accumsan ante orci, at ultricies orci ultrices ultricies. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc dignissim, leo eget maximus dignissim, nibh neque aliquet tellus, eu facilisis dolor neque non metus. Fusce condimentum eros diam, iaculis varius nunc venenatis vel. Nulla venenatis ipsum nec urna ornare, tincidunt pharetra nisi rutrum. Phasellus sed elit sed erat placerat lobortis quis consectetur orci. Curabitur suscipit, nibh vitae ultricies feugiat, urna ante laoreet elit, mattis tristique massa justo quis augue.rn<p style="margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;">Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean rhoncus enim in orci viverra pharetra. Donec lorem orci, commodo sagittis orci a, ultrices feugiat eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque dignissim libero ac maximus tristique. Quisque posuere hendrerit ligula non ornare. Aliquam a libero non risus feugiat dignissim id at sem."

but i want this:
"
Cras lacinia, magna vel finibus mattis, neque nisl gravida nulla, vel posuere dui nisi vel arcu. Integer tristique dignissim dolor, vel tristique orci. Ut auctor ultrices ullamcorper. Suspendisse in eros nisi. Nulla sodales vel nulla quis sollicitudin. Sed suscipit nulla id maximus eleifend. Phasellus sed enim vel dui interdum cursus. Morbi ipsum nibh, iaculis nec iaculis vitae, malesuada at libero. Nunc convallis iaculis ex, vel gravida odio sollicitudin nec. Fusce volutpat mi augue, ut efficitur mi aliquet sit amet. In luctus viverra metus, posuere suscipit nulla molestie sed. Etiam sem nunc, ultricies eget quam non, elementum commodo nibh. Nullam lorem diam, tempor id vehicula eu, dignissim quis arcu. Sed accumsan suscipit lacus in pretium. Donec venenatis turpis ac commodo suscipit.

Pellentesque enim lacus, volutpat ut rutrum vel, venenatis vel velit. Aliquam accumsan ante orci, at ultricies orci ultrices ultricies. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc dignissim, leo eget maximus dignissim, nibh neque aliquet tellus, eu facilisis dolor neque non metus. Fusce condimentum eros diam, iaculis varius nunc venenatis vel. Nulla venenatis ipsum nec urna ornare, tincidunt pharetra nisi rutrum. Phasellus sed elit sed erat placerat lobortis quis consectetur orci. Curabitur suscipit, nibh vitae ultricies feugiat, urna ante laoreet elit, mattis tristique massa justo quis augue.

Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean rhoncus enim in orci viverra pharetra. Donec lorem orci, commodo sagittis orci a, ultrices feugiat eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque dignissim libero ac maximus tristique. Quisque posuere hendrerit ligula non ornare. Aliquam a libero non risus feugiat dignissim id at sem.
"

Comment: A short example of text will do, large amounts don't always add to the question.

Comment: If you just want to enter text, wouldn't a textarea field be enough?

Comment: Please clarify the code from the description

Answer (score 0):

When you output the content, while in a loop, you can sanitize the output to remove any and all tags using `wp_strip_all_tags`.

> Properly strip all HTML tags including script and style.

```
<?php wp_strip_all_tags( the_content(), true ); ?>
```

(`true` or `false` for line breaks).

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/

Alternatively, you can remove any auto `<p>` tag applied as line break by removing the `wpautop` via `remove_filter` in your `function.php` file.

```
<?php remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); ?>
```